# What does the (statistical) operator $\mathbb{D}$ usually mean?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, notation, kullback-leibler

Im reading and trying to understand the following paper on "Disentangled State Space Representations" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.03255.pdf).

In the derivation of the KL-loss term the authors used the symbol [image: \mathbb{D}] . Here is a part of the equation (see paper p. 11):

[image]

I have never seen the use of [image: \mathbb{D}] in such a context and wondering what it means here. Also in this nice [overview](https://mathvault.ca/hub/higher-math/math-symbols/probability-statistics-symbols/) of statistic-symbols there is no such symbol mentioned. Maybe someone here has an idea?

Best reguards

Comment: Symbols in mathematics do not have fixed meanings, if I were you I would be puzzled as well as the authors do not seem to explain what do they mean by the symbol anywhere in the paper.

Comment: Possibly a typo ($\mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{D}$)? Thinking behind this is that most the work is based on KL divergences which can be expressed as expectations. You could email the authors, there is an email address on the first page. In the past, I have emailed authors about (potential) mistakes in papers and some have been happy to clarify the issue

Comment: You can use math typesetting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It looks like a set, not an operator. Usually double-lined symbols refer to the highest order set, e.g. $\mathbb N$ contains all natural numbers $N$. Maybe $\mathbb D$ refers to the set of all emenents $D$ that correspond to the condition below $q(\cdot)$. (I haven't looked at the paper admittedly.)

Comment: Looking at the comments there doesn't seem to be a clear answer. Maybe just e-mail the authors? They provided e-mail in the footnote.

Comment: I cannot find this in the original.  Equation (11) doesn't look anything like this.  Something very much like it appears in equation (14) but there's an "$\mathbb E$" there, not $\mathbb D.$  I would guess you have a problem with your Adobe reader.

Comment: @whuber I see $\mathbb D$ on **page** 11 (after the works cited)